# Natbib: How to show names of all authors for pieces with 3 or more authors the first time a piece is cited, and use "et al." for subsequent citations

Tags: citing, natbib, authoryear

I am submitting a paper to a journal that requires the following citation format:

- If a work has two authors, give both names every time you cite it.
- For three through six authors, give all names the first time, then
  use “et al.” in citations.

Example:

**First citation**: (Foster, Whittington, Tucker, Horner, Hubbard, & Grimm, 2000).

**Subsequent citation**: (Foster et al., 2000).

How can I achieve this in [`natbib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib), for both `\citet{}` and `\citep{}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Load the `natbib` package with the option `longnamesfirst`.

From page 8 of the package's user guide:

> Some publishers require that the first citation of any given reference
> be given with the full author list, but that all subsequent ones with the
> abbreviated list. Include the option `longnamesfirst` to enable this for
> `natbib`.

Just to be clear: The `longnamesfirst` option will show all authors' names even if a piece has *more than 6* authors. You didn't specify what should be done in such cases; if, in fact, you're supposed to be employing the APA6 truncation method for such pieces, you should not use the `natbib` citation management package. In its place, you should probably employ the `apacite` package (with the option `natbibapa`, if you wish to enable the `\citet` and `\citep` macros) and the `apacite` bibliography style.

---

*Addendum, Dec. 2021*: The suggestion made in the preceding paragraph -- *viz.*, to employ the `apacite` package and `apacite` bib style -- was fine back in January 2016. In the meantime, the APA has issued another (seventh) set of formatting guidelines for citation call-outs and bibliographies. If you need to adhere to *current* APA formatting guidelines, you should prepare to switch from `apacite` and BibTeX to `biblatex` (with option `style=apa`) and biber.